Is it safe for a Django backend's GCP storage bucket to be public?
I'm pretty confused by the permissions options for GCP's buckets. I have a Django Rest API that is dockerized and hosted on Cloud Run. I want the API to be accessible only by the client (which is hosted on Firebase), when running migrations on Cloud Build, and obviously Django admin.
I thought the bucket's permissions should be "Not public" with "Fine-grained: Object-level ACLs enabled". But when I try to run collectstatic while connected to cloud-sql-proxy I get this error: The member bindings allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers are not allowed since public access prevention is enforced.
I'm sure I can solve this probably by removing public access prevention, but does that present any security vulnerabilities? I tried granting access to the principal under my email address and the default compute service account, but it doesn't seem to help.

Could you elaborate what are you storing in the bucket? And how you are trying to access it?

The bucket contains Django admin HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Enabling Public Access Prevention basically never exposes your data to the public internet [1]. The full behaviour of that feature is [2]:

Resources subject to public access prevention have the following behavior:
Requests to buckets and objects authorized using allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers fail with an HTTP 401 or 403 status code.
Existing IAM policies and ACLs granting access to allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers remain in place but are overridden by public access prevention.
Requests to create buckets or objects with allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers in their IAM policies or ACLs fail, with the following exception:
If a bucket has a default object ACL containing allUsers, requests to create objects in that bucket succeed. The ACLs for such objects contain allUsers, but allUsers is overridden by public access prevention. Requests to add allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers to an IAM policy or ACL fail with 412 Precondition Failed.

What you want to do is create a service account with the appropriate permission, since service accounts are part of your project, they are not considered public. You can check the steps provided here - Authentication Settings.
[1]. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/public-access-prevention#should-you-use
[2]. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/public-access-prevention#enforced

Thanks. So if this is for an API accessed by a website and mobile apps I'm building, how would the clients be associated with a service account?
